# Android, Java: Improve quality of Bitmap with getDrawingCache()

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap, drawingcache

I have a `dialog` and convert it to a `bitmap`. Then I want so send it with the Sharing Intent:

```
        Bitmap cs = null;
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        v1.buildDrawingCache(true);
        cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cs);
        v1.draw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContext().getContentResolver(), cs, "MyImage", null);
        Uri file = Uri.parse(path);
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, file);
        getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share image using"));
```

`v1` is the parent of a `TextView` in the dialog (`v1` is what I want to send). 
If I send the bitmap now it has a really bad quality. How can I improve that?

Comment: Hello, I am also facing the same problem. Did you found any solution for this ?

Comment: Hello, I did this: OutputStream outStream = null;
   try {
    outStream = getContext().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(file);
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   cs = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(cs, cs.getWidth()*2, cs.getHeight()*2, true);
   cs.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream); It helped a bit.

Comment: Thank you will surely try out this solution in my application.